# Bash - How to share constants between scripts?

Tags: bash, constants, code-cleanup

Is there a way to make it so that there isn't a list of constants at the top of every bash script i have? I have a lot of readonly constants for formatting and such but having them at the top of every single one of my scripts takes up space. Is there a way to make a separate script containing all of them and access it or something? or some way to clean it up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a common script that you `source` in your other scripts.

E.g. `source common.sh` will execute that file and you may export variables there.

This is also how files like `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` work, it is sourced when you execute bash (the latter when it is a login shell). When you change `.bashrc`, you can source it again in the running shell for the changes to take effect.